# Different pages for admins and users [userfrosting 0.3.1]

Tags: permissions, admin, userfrosting

I want to create different pages for users and admins. It seems that:

```
$app->user->checkAccess('uri_my-whatever-access-rights')
```

does not work for admins, it always validates to true. I don't want the admin to have the same options as a regular user.

This goes for index.php (Slim) as well as the Twig templates (admins see all user menus, even though they are only meant for users).

Bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "admin", do you mean the root user, or do you mean a user that you've added to an "admin" group?

Comment: I meant the "root" user. I suppose regular admin accounts behave as expected? (Will check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i noticed the same behavior on my project. The root user always sees everything, a possible fix would be to simply exclude the 'user_master_id' if you not want to see everything as root.

Something like:

```
if($app->config('user_id_master') == $app->user->id)
```

should do the job.

**Edit:** I checked the User.checkAccess(..) Method. See also the [API](http://www.userfrosting.com/api/source-class-UserFrosting.User.html)

The User with the MasterUserId will see everything (evaluates always true) any other Admin does not see the stuff which it should not see - like defined in the rule(s).

If you want to exclude the root from some pages/entries simply append a suitable routine like `isRoot()` to the `user` model, register it [here](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/userfrosting/models/UserFrosting.php#L157-L160) and you can use it in twig and also in the routing routines.

regards

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the root user is not meant to be used as a day-to-day account.  Rather, it is supposed to be a way for developers or the sysadmin to quickly diagnose and troubleshoot code and access control issues.  The owner of a site should still have their own, non-root account that they use for regular activity.  So, I generally would not exclude the root user from accessing anything.